# Confused with so many writers

Tags: android, file-io

I have a text file `infofile` that want to process and write the processed stuff to an `infotxt` file. The way I do it is simply with this:

```
fos = new FileOutputStream(infotxt);
out = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "Latin1");
fis = new FileInputStream(infofile);
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
     ...process line...
     out.write("\n"+line);
}
br.close();
out.close();
fis.close();
fos.close();
```

However, it seems to me that this is not "optimal" since it writes to a file while processing stuff (or maybe this IS optimal??).

Would it be better to use a `StringBuilder` to build the text first and write to the file after that? Or maybe with a `TextWriter`? Or maybe a `StreamWriter`?? Or ... why are there so many ways of doing this, and which is the best for relatively "small" files?

Thanks!